# Is there any complication for uploading m-commerce application?

Tags: android, ios

Can anyone please tell me is there any need to pay Google play for m-commerce application.If yes,please tell me how much we have to pay for that.I want to know the case of apple too.I am new to this area..So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For Apple: If your app sells physical goods, there is no need to pay apple, but you should implement your billing system. If you sell non-physical goods (like digital content), you have to use In App Purchases. Apple gets 30% and you get 70%.

For Google Play:

> In-app purchases: Developers offering virtual goods or currencies
>   within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's
>   in-app billing service as the method of payment. Developers offering
>   additional content, services or functionality within another category
>   of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app
>   billing service as the method of payment, except: where payment is
>   primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets,
>   or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy
>   subscription); or where payment is for digital content or goods that
>   may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can
>   be played on other music players). Developers must not mislead users
>   about the apps they are selling nor about any in-app services, goods,
>   content or functionality they are selling.

Comment: Can you tell me about android too?